# Error while inserting duplicate records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this code to do commit

```
 public RetornoDTO Commit(EfDbContext _context)
    {
        string erroValidation = String.Empty;
        try
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                var erro =
                    string.Format("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);

                Logger.GetInstance().Erro(erro);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    erroValidation = string.Format("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                    Logger.GetInstance().Erro(erroValidation);
                }
            }
            return new RetornoDTO
            {
                Sucesso = false,
                Mensagem = "Error - Erro " + erroValidation
            };
        }
        return new RetornoDTO { Sucesso = true, Mensagem = "Changes saved!!!" };
    }
```

But when I try to insert a duplicate record the catch statement doesn't work and I receive this error:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.ClienteDoCliente' with unique index 'IX_NomeClienteDoCliente'.The duplicate key value is (Cliente Name Test).
>   The statement has been terminated.

```
Linha 30:             try
Linha 31:             {
Linha 32:                 _context.SaveChanges();
Linha 33:             }
Linha 34:             catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
```

What I need to change to avoid this message?

Comment: You are trying to save data that has a unique constraint. Change the data you insert

Comment: Yes, I want the code doesn't show the stack error but a customized error and Log the error in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your catch is only catching `DbEntityValidationException`. Inserting a duplicate record is not a DbEntityValidationException, but another exception.

You need to add a further `catch` for that kind of exception (or a catch all), or if your current catch code was meant for this issue, correct the exception you are catching.

The error message you get might tell the exact exception for duplicate records; if not, you can try to find it in the manual, or to catch a higher level exception and check in the debugger what the exact exception is.